# Getting pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError when trying to connect to RabbitMQ server

Tags: python, rabbitmq, devops, azure-aks

The rabbitmq is deployed in AKS.Now, I need to connect to the RabbitMQ server using the python using pika library. However, I'm encountering an `AMQPConnectionError` when trying to establish a connection. Here's the relevant code snippet:

NOte: The RabbitMQ UI is accessible through NGINX, which has TLS enabled. I can connect to the RabbitMQ UI from the browser using a username and password, which is working fine, and I can see everything.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import pika
import traceback

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('test', 'test_123')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters("rmqtst.xy.zy.o",
                                       5672,
                                       '/',
                                       credentials)
try:
    # Establish connection
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    print("Connection established successfully.")
    
    # Close the connection
    connection.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed to establish connection.")
    traceback.print_exc()
```

```
#resolves to the IP address 1.3.1.1 according to the DNS server queried
 ~ % nslookup rmqtst.xy.zy.o
Server:     1.2.2.3
Address:    1.2.2.3#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   rmqtst.xy.zy.o
Address: 1.3.1.1
```

[image: service ampq port]

Comment: Is this actually a kubernetes configuration question?

Comment: Thank you for your response. This question related to establishing a connection to RabbitMQ from within  Python script, rather than a Kubernetes configuration problem. However, Kubernetes configuration could potentially be a factor in this issue, especially if network policies or service configurations are causing connectivity problems.Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated